# Regex matching the end of a string with a word

Tags: php, regex

How do I match the end of a regular expression by a word? For example:

```
<h1><a href=...></a>CONTENT</h1>
```

Given that `<h1>` is the start tag, how do I return `<a href=...></a>CONTENT`?

The expression `/< h1>(([<\/h1>\b])*/` does not seem to work

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/383402

Comment: @Borealid: Without even clicking it, I knew which post that was :)

Comment: @Borealid: Give it a rest. There's no nested tags here, nor did the question ask for parsing. Also it's kind of rude to spam it onto every newbie question. http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/73168/148103

Comment: @mario The two web sites mentioned in that response are actually useful, thanks! I'll use them instead. As for applicability: in my experience, one tag becomes two, and then someone puts in an HTML entity, and then you end up with a comment, and before you know it, you're parsing HTML.

Comment: @Borealid: Right, but that's true of everything. You start out with a simple `for` loop, and then requirements change, and new requirements are added, and before you know it you have a 2000-line function. Because everyone knows that you can never, *ever* change your design later. Refactoring is simply out of the question! Right?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What makes most regular expressions difficult, is the fact that they're greedy by default. By making them *ungreedy* using the [`U` modifier](http://php.net/manual/en/reference.pcre.pattern.modifiers.php), writing something like this becomes very trivial. The following should work.

```
/<h1>(.*)<\/h1>/U
```

Comment: @M42 Yes it does, because I made it _ungreedy_. Please read my answer and the link about the U modifier. Or even better, test it yourself.

Answer (score 3):

```
/<h1>([\s\S]*)<\/h1>/
```

I think this should help you out.

Comment: Well then this should do it /<h1>([\x20-\x7E]*)<\/h1>/g